# Selecting layout/content type for new pages

Tags: 2013, publishing

Given a site (SPWeb) with a Pages list associated with two content types (CT) A and B, and corresponding page layouts LayoutA and LayoutB. When  I select "Add a Page" I'm only asked for the name of the page, and I cannot select layout/CT at this stage. Instead, the page is assigned a default CT and default page layout. And since the layouts are associated with different CTs I cannot just switch between the two using the standard "edit page" options.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to allow people to pick layout/CT when creating the page **via the Add a Page** site action?

I'm looking for a solution in code. Currently I'm adding the CTs to the Pages list of the site, and setting the `AssociatedContentType` property of the `PageLayout` objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to the Pages library, click the Documents tab on the ribbon and then the New drop down, you can pick any of the page layouts associated with the library up-front.

Comment: Better than nothing I guess, but still won't do. The users are primarily working in a front-end view with just publishing pages. "Add a Page" is the most natural option for doing just that, and I assumed it would be possible to pick the layout when you add a page. Seems a bit half-baked for a publishing framework not to support that kind of operation in a natural way...

Answer (score 1):

You are not far off. The thing about the *Create new page* options in Site Actions is that it automatically uses a default pagelayout which is decided by SharePoint.

Luckily this default pagelayout can be changed. Go to site settings. Under *Look and feel* click *Pagelayouts and sitetemplates*. At the bottom of this page you'll see the section *Default setting for new pages*. Select the new default pagelayout of your liking and click OK.

Now when you create a new page from Site Actions this pagelayout will be used instead of the old default one. How ever will still not be able to make users choose B instead A. It is A or B. You can then of course edit the page and change pagelayout under the *Page* tab.

Comment: Thansk for the input, but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for. I was hoping for a solution allowing the user creating the page pick the layout/CT before the item is even created. The two CTs aren't directly compatible (associated with two completely different layouts), and since the new item is created with the default CT, only one page layout is available in the Page tab.

Comment: @claesv In that they'll have to go to the Page library and select a CT from the *New* button.